# Selecting and filtering data using Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Suppose I have the following query:

```
 context.Orders.Where(predicate).Select(x => new { propA = x.PropA, propB = x.PropB}).ToList();
```

Does this perform both the where and select functions at the DB/ORM level, returning only the data that satisfy both expressions, or would it return all the results that satisfy the predicate and then perform the select on those?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/I8SY160612-IEnumerable-VS-IQueryable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `IQueryable.Select` method. So it is definitely translated into SQL.From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548743(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The `Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)` method generates a MethodCallExpression that represents calling `Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>`) itself as a constructed generic method. It then passes the MethodCallExpression to the `CreateQuery(Expression)` method of the `IQueryProvider` represented by the Provider property of the source parameter.

You can verify this by using a profiler.Or, try calling an unsupported method in the `Select` and you will get an exception that says `linq to entities does not recognize the method X`, that also verifies the `Select` is converted to `SQL` and not executed in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

It will do both at the DB/ORM level. Results of your query fetched only when you enumerating your IQueriable e.g. calling `ToList()`